# How to disable the selection on UITableViewCell's accessory view only?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, accessoryview

My `UITableViewCell` has an accessory view of `UIButton` on the right edge of the cell. However, the button might not be available to an user and thus I shall disable it via `self.myButton.enabled = false`.

While this makes the cell selection work as usual however, now the selection also reacts to the tap on the button. In other words, while the button is disabled and the user still taps on the button, the tap is now responding to the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

This is not what I want, since it might confuse my users at times. So I want to implement it as follows:

- When the button is available, tapping the cell and tapping the button execute different methods respectively (which I implemented and worked).
- When the button is unavailable, tapping the cell works only on the part of where the button is not located.

Is it possible to set the functionality here?

Comment: Why not just hide the button instead of disabling it?

Comment: @Rog It is a `buy` button in in-app purchase and I want to make it disabled if the request to the Apple server fails. Do you recommend just hiding it?

Comment: Yup fair enough to leave it visible and looking disabled (assume you're using it for in-app purchases). In this case I'd just change the button image / look so it looks disabled but keep enabled == true. Add logic to your tap action to simply return if you had no response from the Apple server.

Comment: Have you tried `button.userInteractionEnabled = false`?

Comment: @Rog I think it is easier, but I would rather stick to the default by Apple :=). But if there's not a good alternative, I'd use it, thanks.

Comment: There's no other alternative. What enabled == false does is pass the touch through to the view underneath, so you will always get the tap on the cell if you disable the button.

Comment: Sorry @Blaszard, my suggestion was wrong. Try using `button.cancelTrackingWithEvent(nil)`, and it won't pass touches. You can do this in the `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` in in the button action.

Comment: You could make the button look disabled (text color change, disable highlighting) and still receive touches. I'm on mobile right now so I can't make a very solid answer.